# how to split a string name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

EDITED: (sorry for the unclear dilemma i have written)

i have change the name into "2015-02-12a00.12.20a67" and please the "name" i have here is just an sample of a filename of an image that i will read from a folder. and the only requirement i have is the output. i want the filename to split into three (date, time, and speed) so that i could store them into the DB.

```
str1 = 2015-02-12
str2 = 00:12:20
str3 = 67
```

how can i do that in vb.net? i found this code

```
Dim TestString As String = "apple pear banana  " 
Dim TestArray() As String = Split(TestString)
Dim LastNonEmpty As Integer = -1

For i As Integer = 0 To TestArray.Length - 1
    If TestArray(i) <> "" Then
        LastNonEmpty += 1
        TestArray(LastNonEmpty) = TestArray(i)
    End If 
Next
```

but it's not for my wants/needs.
anyone please help me..

Comment: When you say `str1 = 2015-02-12` do you really mean `str1 = 2015-02-14`?

Comment: The code you found doesn't see particularly relevant to your problem.  Also, your problem is not clear - is the string always in that exact format?  In that case, [`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be all you need.  If the `image` part is variable, then you may need something else.

Comment: [Here's](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BAwrUv) an example, I'm not removing "image", I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @JAT That would make a nice answer.

Comment: @JAT -- Not quite the output the OP wants.  Outputs "12:12:20" instead of "00:12:20" for the time.

Comment: @roryap Just an "HH" (or two) away though.

Comment: @roryap updated example

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim input = "image2015021400122067"
Const Prefix = "image"
Const YearLength = 4
Const NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths = 2
Dim year = input.Substring(Prefix.Length, YearLength)
Dim month = input.Substring(Prefix.Length + YearLength, NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths)
Dim day = input.Substring(Prefix.Length + YearLength + NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths, NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths)
Const DateSeparator = "-"c
Dim str1 = String.Join(DateSeparator, {year, month, day})
Dim hours = input.Substring(CInt(Prefix.Length + YearLength + NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths * 2), NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths)
Dim minutes = input.Substring(CInt(Prefix.Length + YearLength + NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths * 3), NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths)
Dim seconds = input.Substring(CInt(Prefix.Length + YearLength + NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths * 4), NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths)
Const TimeSeparator = ":"c
Dim str2 = String.Join(TimeSeparator, {hours, minutes, seconds})
Dim str3 = input.Substring(CInt(Prefix.Length + YearLength + NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths * 5), NonYearDateTimeFieldLengths)
```

Please note, this code makes a few assumptions:

1. Your string will always begin with `image`,
2. The fields will always be the same "width", i.e. years will always be 4 characters (duh!) and the other date/time fields will be 2 characters, zero-padded if necessary, just like your provided input string.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with DateTime.ParseExact and string format

```
    Dim datex = "Image2015021400122067"

    Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datex, "'Image'yyyyMMddhhmmssff", Nothing)

    Dim s1 = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    Dim s2 = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

    Dim s3 = dt.ToString("ff")
```

No need to use substring, "Image" is ignored inside the format pattern
 You can test it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/BAwrUv

Comment: i've edited my question @jat.. hmm and also the format of the filename.. :(

Answer (score -2):

Based on:

.NET 4.5

VB.NET program that uses Split

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
' We want to split this input string
Dim s As String = "2015-02-12a00.12.20a67"

' Split string based on spaces
Dim words As String() = s.Split(New Char() {"a"c})

' Use For Each loop over words and display them
Dim word As String
For Each word In words
    Console.WriteLine(word)
Next
End Sub

End Module
```

Output

```
2015-02-12
00.12.20
67
```

i think this could help you a lot.
here is the link http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Comment: how?? split is the most common function, you have to pass the spliting character, here i have passed empty space as a spliting character

Comment: look at his *first* sentence.  the code block is some code he found which will do him no good.

Comment: @MuhammadBashir -- I'm sorry, but you're completely confused on this.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @Plutonix Since [the OP's edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28128025/2) this is actually close to what was asked for (would just want to swap the `" "c` for `"a"c`.)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Great to make the changes, and make it clear. Great work